# Making a histogram of how many particles (x,y,z, and time) pass through different defined 3D regions

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting, histogram

How would you go about creating an algorithm that does the following; makes a histogram of how many particles (x,y,z, and time) pass through different defined 3D regions. Are there any analogous problems I might look at?

To put in other terms, if baseballs were thrown all over the house, knowing the baseball's positions and the dimensions of the rooms in the same coordinate system, how many baseballs passed through the living room, the dining room or the kitchen?

Comment: for every given particle you get a list of points and time? particle1 = [(x1,y1,z1,time1),(x2,y2,z2,t2)], and can you assume the root from point1 to point2 is a straight line?

Comment: Yes you can assume the points between the time steps are a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

Think about monitoring vehicle traffic. If we take a look at [this picture](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/operations/datamodelsims/13082/images/fig02.jpg) of toll booths, each individual toll booth or checkpoint can be defined in 3 dimensions. When someone drives through, a sensor or camera may increment a counter for cars that pass through the specific lane. This process can be taken a step further to sense if the vehicle passing through was a car, truck, or motorcycle **(x, y, or z)** and/or if the car paid the toll. Tolls commonly bill by the amount of axels a vehicle has for example, so distinguishing between type of vehicle will expect payment accordingly. In terms of histograms, we can take this process a step further and say that our counter resets every hour and the data is logged/displayed for each hour. A toll booth plaza may use this system to audit their records to ensure all vehicles paid the toll. Or to make decision as to which toll lanes to keep open and closed based on which lanes drivers pass through more frequently.

The key thing here is that we have some sort of location-sensing-time process that does the following:

**1. Defines each of the 3-dimensional zones**

**2. Senses the entrance of an object into one of the 3-dimensional zones**

**3. Distinguishes the type of object entering the zone (x, y, or z)**

**4. Logs the data for the hour, minute, or other specified time interval**

In other applications, a retail store will commonly seek to sell products in certain areas of the store depending on traffic, age of customer, demographic, etc. This can also be done through tracking traffic with cameras or sensors in the store that enclose an area. Usually, more expensive items or clearance items the store really wants to sell are placed in areas of more frequent traffic as it exposes the product to more people. You'll see this in places like Wal-Mart that put clearance items at the entrance because they need the merchandise gone ASAP and every customer has to pass through the entrance.